# IIS6 host multiple websites under same sub-domain (or something similar)

Tags: iis-6, web-hosting, application

I'm trying to figure out a structure for a hosted application that i'm working on.
I've got a domain lets call it app.company.com (a sub-domain company.com of course) that is setup to redirect to my IIS 6 web server.

I would like to set up one website in IIS for each client that will use this application.
And have the URL schema be like this:

app.company.com/clientA --> would point to ClientA website in IIS

app.company.com/clientB --> would point to ClientB website in IIS

Do you guys have any pointers or best practices for my scenario?

Comment: Are these just separate websites or are you trying to do something special, like pull up the same website via different urls?

Comment: Everything old is new again... that's how they used to do virtual hosts before host headers were universally adopted...

Answer (score 2):

Use a redirector.

app.company.com/CLioentA gets redireted to ClientA.app.company.com.

Pretty much every reverse proxy should do. It can also rewrite the HTML in the pages when needed.

Pretty much the only solution I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Vdirs need to be under the same site unless you front the site with a load balancer or proxy of some sort.

Can you use clientA.company.com?  If so, then you can use the unique domain names (cnames) for each site.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the reply.

No i'm afraid that it wouldn't be acceptible for us to use the clientA.company.com approach.

Comment: Your only option then is to front the sites with a load balancer.  If you're starting fresh, I would recommend IIS 7 + ARR.  You can do layer 7 routing that way.